# Changing a columns width from 60% to 100% on media queries change

Tags: css, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I'm using the [Zurb Foundation 3](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php) framework and I have the following layout.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="eight columns">
    Main content...
  </div>
  <div class="four columns hide-for-medium">
    Sidebar...
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the eight column grid take up 100% of the width when the four column grid [disappears on medium sized displays](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/elements.php)? At the moment on a medium sized display when the four column grid goes to 'display: none', the eight column grid still takes up just eight columns when ideally it would fill 12 columns (full width).

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem, that will make it easier for me to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, it just requires a specific Media Query and overriding the width and float values.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) and (min-width: 768px) { 
  .test { 
    float: none !important; 
    width: auto !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: <th style="width:20%;text-align:center" class="m-datatable__cell m-datatable__cell--sort">
                  <mfDefaultSorter by="DepartmentName">Department Name</mfDefaultSorter>                                                                     for this how to do responsive width(for mobile view) by using media query. <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle" class="m-datatable__cell"><span style="width: 150px;">{{ i+1 }}</span></td>